# How many observations in the output dataset?

Tags: sas

A raw data file is listed below:

```
RANCH,1250,2,1,Sheppard Avenue, "$64,000"
SPLIT,1190,1,1,Rand Street, "$65,850"
CONDON, 1400,2,1,Market Street, "80,050"
TWOSTORY, 1810,4,3,Garris Street, "$107,250"
RANCH, 1500,3,3,Kemble Avenue, "$86,650"
SPLIT, 1615, 4,3, West Drive, "94,450"
SPLIT, 1305, 3,1.5,Graham Avenue, "$73,650"
```

The following is the code:

```
data work.condo_ranch;
    infield "file_specificaton" did;
    input style $ @;
    if style = 'CONDO' or style = 'RANCH' then
    input sqfeet bedrooms baths street $ price: dollar10.;
run;
```

So, I think the output dataset contains 3 observations, while the correct answer is that the output contains 7 observations. Does anyone tell me why? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you expect the output dataset to have only 3 observations.  There is an implied OUTPUT statement at the bottom of the DATA step.  If you want to output only those records where STYLE IN ("CONDO","RANCH") you could add a conditional OUTPUT, e.g.:

```
if style = 'CONDO' or style = 'RANCH' then do;
  input sqfeet bedrooms baths street $ price: dollar10.;
  output;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to output the records where style is CONDO or RANCH you could just change your `THEN` to a semi-colon.  That would make your `IF` statement a `subsetting IF`. So the data step would return at that point and never run the second INPUT or the implied OUTPUT at the end of the step.